# List of function - basis

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I would like to define list of function (make polynomial basis as a set of the functions), and then evaluate value of first/ second function in the set.

I have made set of the fuctions that I have used this:

```
v = Array[x^(# - 1) &, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, x, x^2}
> ```

I have set of points `l = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and I would like to make something like this: `v[[2]]=x` and somehow put value `l[[3]]=3`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `v[[2]] /. x -> l[[3]]` or `With[{x = l[[3]]}, Evaluate@v[[2]]]`?

Comment: Sorry, I am new in Wolfram Mathematica, thank you very much.